# Help With K&Rs Counting Chars Example

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I'm working my way through K&R's 2nd edition, and I've been stumped with this seemingly simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    double c;
    for(c = 0; ((getchar() != EOF) && (getchar() != '\n')); ++c)
        ;
    printf("%.0f\n",c);
}
```

It simply isn't working correctly. I added in the `(getchar() != '\n')` portion to end the program when I press enter, but that doesn't *really* help either.

Here's some sample output, using the `gcc` that comes with Mac OSX 10.6 dev tools.

```
pool-000:Desktop user$ ./a.out 
a
0
pool-000:Desktop user$ ./a.out 
asdf

2
pool-000:Desktop user$ ./a.out 
asfasf

3
```

So something is obviously wrong. I'm on page 18, if that helps. This isn't homework, this is for fun!

Thanks :)

Comment: Looks like you have a few fundamental problems; what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I guess you are not terminating the input with Ctrl+D. Revert to the original implementation (without `!= '\n'`) and press Ctrl+D at the end of your input.

Comment: Thanks, Mehrdad, that was the issue. Much appreciated!If you submit it as an answer, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each call to `getchar()` will wait for a character to be read, so you're reading more than you think per iteration of the loop.

Also, at least in my opinion, a counter is (almost) never a `double`, you should use an integer type such as plain old `int`.

Comment: +1, perhaps bring the `getchar()` info to the top? That *is* the major problem with his code. The use of `double` is secondary.

Comment: It was the second `getchar()` that was causing the problems – thanks! K&R's code had the `double` in it, though.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with doing two "getchar()" operations is that you will read TWO get chars in the conditional test... before you get to the ++c.

Ditch the "EOF" comparison and it should work as you expect.

Comment: Also a good point! Thanks – I've got a better idea of how getchar() works now, and a better idea of how C interprets ctrl-D/EOF.