# Character Counting Example From K&R

Tags: c, eof, kernighan-and-ritchie

**K&R**

**charcter counting Example** 
I am not able to get output as expected in the book.For Example, when I enter a input "I am Back" and press enter it should give back me an answer but its not Why so?

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* count characters in input; 1st version */
main()   {
   long nc;
   nc = 0;
   while (getchar() != EOF)
       ++nc;
   printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

Comment: What it our problem? Are you getting any error?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658436/help-with-krs-counting-chars-example?rq=1

Comment: @l19, no, there is not duplicate. In that question TS reads from console twice.

Comment: You can try the examples in the book also in the following way: `echo some input you want | ./compiled-example` or `cat some-text-file | ./compiled-example`.

Comment: eEnter gives a normal char, newline, `'\n'`, if you want to exit at first enter press test against that (but also still against EOF, in case input does not have any newlines in it).

Answer (score 5):

I think you don't see the output, since you don't send `EOF` from keyboard. So, try to send this by pressing `Ctrl + D`.

Comment: I did type Ctrl+D nothing happens.

Comment: Try to press `ctrl` and `D` at the same time, don't type it. And, what OS are you running?

Comment: Note, on Windows console, it is *ctrl-Z enter* on empty line, not *ctrl-D*.